# Isolate SSH Authentication Failures into Own Log File on RHEL 6.6

Tags: rhel, logs, sshd, rsyslog

This may be impossible, but I've got a case where we want to log SSH authentication failures separately from standard SSH logging on a RHEL 6.6 box.

I am aware we can use `SyslogFacility` with `sshd_config` to specify where to send log data, is it possible to send ***only*** SSH authentication failures via that method?

*Edit*:  If not in `sshd` or `sshd_config`, how can this be done on the syslog side?

Comment: No time to look up that, what I can tell you for sure is that *even* if you cannot do that on sshd side, you have got filtering in the syslog server side that allow you to do pretty much anything you want, including searching words. You simply define a new log file, with a matching source+filter.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro thanks for the hint, but lets assume for a moment I'm a newbie when it comes to handling this in syslog...

Comment: (I hinted in the last message I have not got time right now. Will answer later on if in the meanwhile you have not got a solution)

Comment: (@RuiFRibeiro OK, didn't mean to say ou had to answer now :P  I also added an edit to the question in case someone else beats you to it :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rsyslog` makes this relatively easy, since you can match aspects of whatever message arrives.

Include a snippet like this (in my case I put a `*.conf` file into `/etc/rsyslog.d/`):

```
if $programname == 'sshd' then {
    if $msg contains 'Invalid user' then { # adjust to your needs
        *.* -/var/log/sshd-fails.log
    }
    stop # discard all other messages from sshd
}
```

Documentation can be found [here](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/filters.html).

Answer (score 3):

Syslog is definitely the way to go on this one.  How you write the rules depends on whether you're using rsyslog or syslog-ng but for syslog-ng add the following to the `/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf` file.

```
destination ssh_auth_fail { file("/path/to/file.log"); };
filter f_ssh_auth_fail { message("regex to match desired lines"); };
log { source(src); filter(f_ssh_auth_fail); destination(ssh_auth_fail); };
```

Comment: Any chance you have an `rsyslogd` approach?  Since that's what's on the systems right now...

Comment: @ThomasW.: see my answer regarding rsyslog.